# this mean what ，success or fail install wechaty

Tags: node.js, npm

[image]

help me Chinese

install wechaty error for this：

```sh
root@azLinux:~/wechaty# npm install wechaty

up to date, audited 349 packages in 2s

31 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

23 vulnerabilities (16 moderate, 7 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details
```

Comment: There are no errors here